# How to test a Ktor module with Koin?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

I have a module with installed Koin. I need to mock some injected dependencies to perform tests. I cannot find anywhere how to do it correctly. Can you tell me how to do it?

```
class AudioFilesHandlerTest : DescribeSpec(), KoinTest {

private val deviceAuthService by inject<DeviceAuthenticationService>() // it should provide mocked object

    init {
        describe("AudioFilesHandler") {
            val audioFilesUri = "/api/audio-files"

            describe(audioFilesUri) {
                describe("when device is registered") {
                    val product = createProduct() // Factory for tests
                    val device = createDevice(product = product)
                    every { deviceAuthService.challenge(product.productId, device.deviceId) } returns device // this line doesn't work

                    describe("and transcription or audio params are missing") {
                        it("should returns 400") {
                            withApplication(testEnv) {
                                val call = handleRequest(uri = audioFilesUri, method = HttpMethod.Post) {
                                    val boundary = "WebAppBoundary"
                                    addHeader(ContentType, FormData.withParameter("boundary", boundary).toString())
                                    addHeader("productId", product.productId)
                                    addHeader("deviceId", device.deviceId)
                                }

                                call.response.status() shouldBe HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a working Ktor sample project where the dependency for Basic Authentification is mocked in a test https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/b1437e9a4d3f3613b0a1f311f718a76f.  The issue could be in the `mockk` library. Do you have that problem without using it?

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. Your example showed me my mistake. I don't use an embedded server. I have registered all modules in the application.config file. When I run tests all modules were started with all installed plugins. So...I created a new application.config file to tests this specific module (I don't start a module that has installed the Koin plugin now). In test classes, I start Koin and set my mocked objects, and it works perfectly ;)